# How to zoom to bounding box in mapbox?

Tags: android, mapbox

I am using `easeCamera` method to zoom map to specific boundingbox, but it is not working. It zoom out too much.
I know that my northeast and southwest is correct.

This is my code :

```
LatLng northeast = new LatLng(maxy, maxx);
LatLng southwest = new LatLng(miny, minx);

LatLngBounds latLngBounds = new LatLngBounds.Builder()
    .include(northeast)
    .include(southwest)
    .build();

mapView.invalidate();

MainActivity.this.mapboxMap.easeCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(latLngBounds, 1), 5000);
```

and this is result :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found what the problem is. In my layout xml file, I removed `app:mapbox_cameraZoom` attribute that I have set and the problem is fixed .

```
<com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:mapbox_cameraTargetLat="33.698659"
    app:mapbox_cameraTargetLng="46.413015"
    app:mapbox_cameraTilt="60"
    app:mapbox_cameraZoom="9"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making a smaller bounding box so that the camera is where you want it.

Try passing in all of the icon coordinates to the `LatLngBounds.Builder()` rather than just setting the two bounding box coordinates. That's what's done in https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/fit-camera-in-bounding-box.